# Why populate and exec do not work with aync/await functions?

Tags: node.js, database, mongoose, model

I have 2 **mongoose models** `Task` and `User`, and I have established a **relationship** between them. In the task,

I referenced the owner of that task using the ref as follows:

```
const taskSchema = new Schema({
    description: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true
    },
    completed: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
    },
    owner: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    }
});
```

And in the User I use the virtual property feature to get the user's tasks when needed :

```
userSchema.virtual("tasks", {
    ref: "Task",
    localField: "_id",
    foreignField: "owner",
});
```

I would like to know why the exec function is not working with `async/await` following function :

```
const main = async () => {
    const task = await Task.findById("6420aeeebda4e48924667034");

    task.populate('owner').exec()
        .then((task) => {
            console.log(task.owner)
        });
}
```

where it returns an error saying: `exec is not a function`.

while the following non async function works :

```
const main =  () => {
        Task.findById("6420aeeebda4e48924667034").populate('owner').exec()
        .then((task) => {
            console.log(task.owner)
        });
}
```

Same thing when trying to populate the tasks of a user that are associated with him/her.

Also, I would like to know why the [mongoose latest version docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) uses the following example that by the way did not work, and the **IDE** indicated that the exec returns a **Promise** :

> ```
> Person.
>   findOne({ name: 'Ian Fleming' }).
>   populate('stories'). // only works if we pushed refs to children
>   exec(function(err, person) {
>     if (err) return handleError(err);
>     console.log(person);
>   });
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is mixing together two different function syntaxes. It should work if you leave out `.exec()`:

```js
const main = async () => {
    const task = await Task.findById("6420aeeebda4e48924667034");
    await task.populate('owner')
    console.log(task.owner)
}
```

Here I am calling [populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#Document.prototype.populate) on an already loaded document. This returns a promise if no callback is given. No `.exec()` needed.

`exec` is only needed if you are calling [populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#Query.prototype.populate()) on a query such as the other two examples you included. In this case `populate` returns a query, which could be chained with more filters / populates etc., so it needs the `exec` call.

The two populate links I give are to two different parts of the mongoose documentation.

Comment: Thank you I didn't know that there is a populate for Query and a populate for a Document